# PHP and HTML File Extensions Causing Trouble with htaccess and mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, iframe, file-extension

I have a site where the `htaccess` is displaying pages with PHP extensions like so:

`example.com/company/partners`

(has the file name `partners.php`)

Now, on one page, the EULA page, I have to link it like this to make it work:

`example.com/company/eula.php`

because when I got to

`example.com/company/eula`

the browser shows the HTML file that appears in an `iframe` on the page:

`example.com/company/eula.html`

When viewing the page

`example.com/company/eula.php` the `eula.html` appears in the `iframe` as expected but I would like to be able to actually go to

`example.com/company/eula` and see the same thing.

Does this make sense? It's as if the files are being confused. Here is my `htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]
```

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe adding a similar rule?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: After I wrote the question and then thought about, it occurred to me that something like that would work. Thanks for firming that up. Your method worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to prevent this from happening is to simply rename the `eula.html` file so it doesn't conflict.